# How to consider daylight savings while converting utc to timezone

Tags: javascript, momentjs, utc, moment-timezone

Why its not considering daylight savings in moment js.

```
const date_string = '2021-02-23T23:24:21Z';
const date_string1 = '2021-05-01T23:24:21Z';
console.log(moment.utc(date_string).tz("America/New_York").format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A'))
console.log(moment.utc(date_string1).tz("America/New_York").format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A'))
```

### log values:

```
//"02/23/2021 06:24:21 PM"

//"05/01/2021 06:24:21 PM"
```

Is momentjs default not consider daylight saving time and does it need to calculate and do add ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe using this exact code in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lwd9tsv/2/). Logs are `"02/23/2021 06:24:21 PM"` and `"05/01/2021 07:24:21 PM"`, respsectively.

Comment: Thanks @esqew , the fiddle you shared it worked.  Looks like, something wrong where I have been using on editor, https://jsfiddle.net/awzfs1ch/2/ .   Its good now. thanks.

Comment: It seems the inclusion of `moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js` instead of the (ostensibly broader) `moment-timezone-with-data.min.js` is likely the cause of this, but I'm not familiar enough with the library to say for certain. Certainly tangential, but I would recommend removing this dependency on `momentjs` altogether (among other reasons, it's in "maintenance-only mode" and will likely be deprecated in the future) and instead opt to use the more modern built-in `Date` API, which should be more than capable of performing tasks like the one you're illustrating here.

Comment: Yes, I just got replaced that moment library and it works now.   (I was keep using wrong js library) https://jsfiddle.net/awzfs1ch/3/     . Thanks @esqew

Answer (score 1):

Pass both the date string and the timezone to the `moment.tz` constructor, as it is DST aware:

`moment.tz(date_string, "America/New_York").format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss A')`

[There's more detail here in the Moment Timezone docs](https://codesandbox.io/s/momentjs-daylight-savings-time-75huj?file=/src/index.js):

Here's a working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/momentjs-daylight-savings-time-75huj?file=/src/index.js

Comment: this gives same result 6:24:21 for both the logs. https://jsfiddle.net/awzfs1ch/2/